# Slicing numpy arrays in a for loop

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I have a multidimentional numpy array of elasticities with one of the dimensions being "age-groups" (0-92 years) and the other "income-groups" (low/high income).

I would like to create a table with the mean elasticities for each combination of subgroups using a for loop.

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

elasticity = np.random.rand(2,92)
print(elasticity.shape)

income = ['i0','i1']
age_gr= [':18','18:']

table = {}
for i in range(len(age_gr)):
    for j in range(len(income)):
        key = age_gr[i]+"_"+income[j]
        table[key] = np.mean(elasticity[age_gr[i],j])
print(table)
```

My problem is that "age_gr[i]" gives me an error "IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
". In reality I have many more age-groups, so I can't do this manually.

I would like to have something like this as a result:

[image]

with ... representing the mean of elasticities for the sub-group.

EDIT: Age dimension runs from 0-92 years NOT (below/above 18 years) as stated before.

Answer (score 0):

The exact expected output is unclear, but for sure you cannot use a `':18'` string and expect it to behave like a `slice` (`slice(None, 18)`).

You can use a function to convert:

```
import numpy as np

elasticity = np.random.rand(2,92)
print(elasticity.shape)

income = ['i0','i1']
age_gr= [':18','18:']

def str_to_slice(s):
    return slice(*(int(x) if x.isdigit() else None for x in s.split(':')))

table = {}
for i in range(len(age_gr)):
    for j in range(len(income)):
        key = age_gr[i]+"_"+income[j]
        table[key] = np.mean(elasticity[str_to_slice(age_gr[i]), j])
print(table)
```

Output:

```
{':18_i0': 0.19273470668594983,
 ':18_i1': 0.484071263606304,
 '18:_i0': nan,
 '18:_i1': nan}
```